# Problema al redimensionar imagen manteniendo aspecto

Tags: java, android-studio

estoy intentando mantener el aspecto de una imagen al establecer un ancho fijo. Me da el siguiente error: “width or height must be > 0 for resize”

Este es el fragmento de codigo que realiza el redimencionamiento:

```
public String getStringImagen(Bitmap bmp) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    // Dividimos el ancho final por el ancho de la imagen original
    float proporcion = 1200 / (float) bitmap.getWidth();

    // y después multiplicamos el resultado por la altura de la imagen original para conseguir la altura final
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,1200,bitmap.getHeight() * (int) proporcion,false);

    //Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 1000, 800, false);
    resizedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,80,baos);
    //bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Es importante no realizar operaciones aritmeticas dividiendo entre 0 por ejemplo en este caso donde el ancho del bitmap puede ser 0:

```
 float proporcion = 1200 / (float) bitmap.getWidth();
```

Con respecto a el mensaje:

> width or height must be > 0 for resize

me parece que el problema es simplemente que no esta pudiendo obtener las medidas del bitmap original correctamente, te sugiero que al obtener el Bitmap que envias al método `getStringImagen(Bitmap bmp)` lo obtengas usando un Handler para dar un tiempo para obtener correctamente el bitmap y sus propiedades:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //*Obtiene bitmap!
        }
    }, 1000);
```